# Easy way to stop referral spam

Tags: linux, .htaccess, spam, referrals, referrer-spam

I am looking for an easy solution for referral spam. I am receiving hits from thousands of referral websites. They are targeting one of the images "tick.gif".  Following is the screenshot of the "Visitors" page of cPanel.

[image]

I am blocking the websites via htaccess file with the following code.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} badsite.com [NC,OR]

But the list getting bigger day by day and now it is 2123 number of websites which are blocked by htaccess. Is there any other method to block the sites? I have hosted my website in a VPS with root access.

Comment: Why do you need to block these requests in the first place? What are you doing with those referrers, that it would matter that these entries are in there?

Comment: It consumes bandwidth. 43 bytes for each ping. Thousands of pings every minute. Those are showing 0 bytes in the screenshot, are links blocked by htaccess.

Comment: Really? 43kB each minute are an issue for your site?

Comment: Sorry, if I couldn't make it clear. It's not 43 Bytes per minute. It's thousands of 43 bytes per minute. Actually my problem is the bandwidth consumption. According to Awstats bandwidth consumption is very little, 100 MB per day. But according to cPanel -> Bandwidth it's 1 GB per day. I can't get from where the consumption is happening.